# Beautifulsoup not returning all text on webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to webscrape a site but Beautifulsoup does not return all the text visible when just looking at the webpage. Please see code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open("data.txt", "w")
url = "https://www.hiltongrandvacations.com/en/resorts-and-destinations"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
f.write(str(soup))
f.close()
```

For example, the following text is visible on the webpage but not returned by Beautifulsoup (written to a text file):
Grand Pacific Palisades Resort

I tried different parsers (html, lxml) but still not getting it. Also, does not seem like text is generated by Javascript, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The data you see is loaded dynamically via JavaScript. You can use this example to load the data:

```
import json
import requests


payload = {"locations":[],"amenities":[],"vacationTypes":[],"page":1,"pageSize":9}
api_url = 'https://www.hiltongrandvacations.com/sitecore/api/ssc/apps/PropertySearch'

data = requests.put(api_url, json=payload).json()

# uncomment this to prin all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some info on screen:
for card in data['Cards']:
    print(card['Title'])
    print(card['Description'])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Sunrise Lodge, a Hilton Grand Vacations Club
Revel in the peak of adventure
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The District by Hilton Club
A capital experience in the capital city
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Central at 5th by Hilton Club
At the heart of city life
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Hilton Club – New York
Make a break for the Big Apple.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Residences by Hilton Club
Wake up in the city that never sleeps.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Grand Pacific Palisades Vacation Resort
A window to the Pacific Ocean. 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Carlsbad Seapointe Resort
A quintessentially Californian vacation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hilton Grand Vacations Chicago Downtown/Magnificent Mile
A sky-high sanctuary amidst the big-city bustle
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hilton Grand Vacations Club at Trump International Hotel Las Vegas

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej - going to give it a shot, appreciate your help.

Comment: I looked deeper into your solution and with some review noted that one can see the api_url and payload by inspecting the XHR elements from the webpage. What I want to do is scrape the details of a property (eg. https://www.hiltongrandvacations.com/en/resorts-and-destinations/utah/sunrise-lodge-a-hilton-grand-vacations-club) once you've clicked the link for the property from the home page.  I can't seem to get this info from the current specified api. Any ideas? I appreciate all the help here.

Comment: Try asking another question describing your current requirement as the one you asked in the first place has been resolved @Franz.

Answer (score 0):

could try:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

that should return everything on the webpage

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of parsing this web page using selenium. It allows you to emulate user behavior: wait till page is loaded, scroll down to locations, activate locations dropdown button, choose one of the locations (Utah in this example), click it, wait till new page will be loaded and extract some information from it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
#chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('<PATH_TO_CHROME_DRIVER>',chrome_options=chrome_options)

# delay (how long selenium waits for element to be loaded)
DELAY = 30

# maximize browser window
wd.maximize_window()

# load page via selenium
wd.get("https://www.hiltongrandvacations.com/en/resorts-and-destinations")

# wait until results table will be loaded
results = WebDriverWait(wd, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(), "Results")]')))

# find locations button, scroll down to it, click it
locations_button = WebDriverWait(wd, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Locations")]')))
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", locations_button)
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", locations_button)

# find utah checkbox, scroll down to it, click it
utah_checkbox = WebDriverWait(wd, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(), "Utah")]')))
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", utah_checkbox)
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", utah_checkbox)

# find link to utah
utah_link = WebDriverWait(wd, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@title="Sunrise Lodge, a Hilton Grand Vacations Club Park City, Utah, Revel in the peak of adventure"]')))
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", utah_link)
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", utah_link)

# find description
description = WebDriverWait(wd, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'image-and-intro__description')))

print(description.text)
```

Optionally it can be combined with BeautifulSoup as well in cases when selenium alone is not enough.